# Operations with complex numbers

Tags: c++

I'd like to know how to perform some simple operations with complex numbers without using the real and the imaginary parts separately.

Example:

```
complex<double> A(0.0, 1.0);
complex<double> B;
B = A * 2 + A;
```

It doesn't compile:

> error C2678: binary '*' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::complex' (or there is no acceptable conversion)).

I read it's a problem of conversion.  It's a real problem, especially in the case of more complex code.

Is there a way to do operations with complex numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a conversion issue.  Maybe specify the constant 2 as a floating point value:

```
B = A * 2.0 + A;
```

Comment: So If i had a integer value, first I need to convert it, is it?

Comment: @Ale:  If by convert, you mean cast, then yes.  `B = A * (double)myint + A;`

Answer (score 3):

It is a conversion issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  complex<double> A (5.0, 10.0);
  complex<double> B;

  B = A * 2.0 + A; 
  cout << "B = " << B << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

works rather nicely.

Answer (score 2):

C++ provides **operator overloading**, which can be a very easy and friendly way to handle that.

```
Complex operator + (Complex a, Complex b)
{
    return Complex(a.real + b.real, a.imag + b.imag);
}

Complex operator * (Complex a, double b)
{
    return Complex(a.real * b, a.imag * b);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to use it. Do I have to implement them in my class?

Comment: You can implement it both inside and outside of a class. The one I wrote is for outside declaration. They must be `friend` functions if the numbers are `private`. For declaring them inside, you'll have to provide only the right-hand operand.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_overloading.html": Here you can find some nice examples. Fortunately they're written for complex numbers!